# node.js server connecting with other ws server

Tags: node.js, websocket, connection

I'm trying to connect with ws module to websocket server, connection is established successfully, but I always receive an error about connections limit (Allowed only 2).
Maybe somebody knows how i can set max count of socket connections with ws module?

Comment: How about just making one or two connections to the server?

Comment: How I can do it?
const ws = new WebSocket(serverURL);  I use it just once..

Comment: Try adding a `console.log` right in front of it to make sure that it's only called once.

Comment: Yeap, even with console.log it runs just once. Maybe there is some options or configurations... I looked over ws documendation and didn't find any useful info about connection limits. Template of my connection string: 
http://88.*.*.*:3030/ws

Comment: If you only make one connection, you don't need a connection limit because one connection is within the imposed limits by the server. Perhaps the server will allow only 2 connections per IP-number, or something? Do you control the server?

Comment: I controle just my node middleware (websocket client), to the other server (websocket server) I don't have access..

Comment: The doc for other server (websocket server) says - "limit of connections per host which client can establish, this value is configurable, but client can expect to be allowed to open from 1 to 5 connections per host"

Comment: "per host" sounds like "per IP". If you only open one connection per process, and you start only one process, there's not much else you can do to improve the client-side of things (apart from making sure that there really _is_ only one connection per _public_ IP-number, so if you have co-workers that may be using the same server you might run out of those allowed 2 connections pretty quickly).

Comment: Thanks for you time!